# MS Excel VBA -Exiting Loop

Tags: vba, excel

UPDATED:

```
Lastrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        DurcurrRowIn = currRowIn
        Do
        DurcurrRowIn = DurcurrRowIn + 1
                Set DurlookFor = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(currRowIn, "C")   ' value to find
                Set Durlookforin = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & DurcurrRowIn & ":C" & Lastrow)
                'Set Durlookforin = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
                 On Error Resume Next
            DurStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wb.ActiveSheet.Range("F" & DurcurrRowIn & ":F" & Lastrow), WorksheetFunction.Match(DurlookFor, Durlookforin, 0))
            DurEnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wb.ActiveSheet.Range("G" & DurcurrRowIn & ":G" & Lastrow), WorksheetFunction.Match(DurlookFor, Durlookforin, 0))
            DurStart = Format(DurStart, "mm-dd-yyyy")
            Dur1 = DurEnd - DurStart
            Dur = Dur + Dur1
         Loop Until Durlookforin Is Nothing
```

Need help exiting the loop once all the employeeIDs have been found with the Index/Match

Here is a sample of my worksheet:

Test Excel

[image: Test Excel]

Comment: MATCH returns the relative location not the row number.  For example  you are starting at row 14 for your first match, If the value is found there in row 14 the MATCH will return one.  With the first criterion in the INDEX being the full column F it would return the value in F1 not F14.  You will need to either limit the first range to the same size and rows of the MATCH or add the Starting row of the Match Function to what is returned.

Comment: @ScottCraner You sir are a tremendous help!!

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you help me with exiting the new loop when the code cannot find any more employee ID's within column C that match.

Comment: One should not change the question but post a new one.  There are many people who will not look at this again as they see it as answered in the comment above.  Please revert this back to the original and ask a new question.  One hint: Durstart and DurEnd will not change from the prior loops values when the Match does not find anything.  So test if they are 0 or "" depending on what it is declared Or matches the value from the last loop, which you will need to store in another variable that gets updated each loop.

Comment: Okay I will try this sorry I am an excel vba newb and I was not allowed to post another question for 90 minutes. I greatly appreciate your help! Trying to save myself days of manual work.